# Xerox Phaser 6110 driver for OpenSolaris

Tags: unix

Could anyone please tell me how to install the Xerox Phaser 6110 driver on my OpenSolaris box, I am a newbe and have limited shell scripting skills.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/) and [this](http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/INSTALL):

> Unpack:
>       $ wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
>       $ tar zxf foo2zjs.tar.gz
>       $ cd foo2zjs
>
> Compile:
>       $ make
>
> Get extra files from the web, such as .ICM profiles (for color correction)
>   and firmware.  Select the model number for your printer:
>   $ ./getweb 6110     # Get Xerox Phaser 6110 and 6110MFP .ICM files
>
> If you use CUPS to manage your printers, you must restart cupsd:
>       # make cups
>
> OR
>   $ sudo make cups
>
> Test operation of programs. Skip this if you don't have the exact same
>   version of Ghostscript that I have, ghostscript 8.60 (2007-08-01), because
>   it will not pass since different versions of Ghostscript generate different
>   raster images:
>       # make test
>
> Create printers (Solaris 11+)
>       # printmgr

See the linked page for more instructions and more information specific to your OS and printer model.

Note: I have no first-hand experience with this driver or these instructions so buyer beware.